# RabbitMQ Crashes if Component Crashes

Tags: rabbitmq

There are multiple applications running individually and talk from other components by RabbitMQ and REST APIs.

All components or applications are using same default exchange of RabbitMQ with different queues.

RabbitMQ is crashing due to  below scanario:
1) One application has consumer as well as producer.
2) Application crashes after some point of time may be due to heady load of data or processing
3) Then whole RabbitMQ is crashed.

Is this happening due to same exchange used by all application's consumer and producer?

Shall I use different exchange for each components or applications